# Rerouting request to second Kestrel hosted project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project that has a public facing website with an admin login area located within an admin oipath, ie: `/admin/`.

As the admin area is growing I'm becoming increasingly keen to move it into a separate project.

With this in mind, is it possible to reroute all requests that hit `/admin/` to the separate project? For instance:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Map("/admin/", builder =>
    {
        // reroute traffic to admin project
    });
}
```

Comment: A whole different server instance? Try this Proxy middleware: https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/blob/dev/samples/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy.Samples/Startup.cs#L16

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to configure that in a reverse-proxy server (IIS or Nginx)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement you own middleware: may use [Proxy middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy/ProxyMiddleware.cs) as example of rerouting.